# Multiple selects with "union all" not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Query not working:

```
select * from
    (select
        department as "Delegación",
         company as Compañía,
         config as "Configuración Vehículos",
         docs as "Documentos Vehículos",
         count(distinct idClientTruck) as vehículos,
         sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos Vehículos",
         round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% Docs. Vehículos"
      from
         (
         select
           cd.name as department,
           cfg_g.name as config, 
           c.businessname as company, 
           (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
           wv.idClientTruck as idEntity, 
           cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup as idWidocConfigGroup, 
           cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
           cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
           a.idstatus as idStatus, 
           if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko 
         from
           widoc_config_group cfg_g
             join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
               join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
             join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
             join widoc_vehicle wv on wv.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wv.idstatus=71001
             join client_truck t on t.idclient_truck=wv.idclienttruck and t.idstatus_truckpart=33005
             join widoc_fulfill_vehicle fv on fv.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fv.idwidocvehicle=wv.idwidocvehicle
             left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wv.idClientTruck
             left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
         where
         cfg_g.idclient = 3683
             #wc.idclientAssociated = 3683
             and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
             and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
              )v 
               ) t UNION ALL
    (select
        config as "Configuración Conductores",
        docs as "Documentos Conductores",
        count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
        sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos Conductores",
        round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% Docs. Conductores"
     from
        (
        select 
           cd.name as department,
           cfg_g.name as config, 
           c.businessname as company, 
           (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
           wd.idDriver as idEntity, 
           cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup as idWidocConfigGroup, 
           cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
           cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
           a.idstatus as idStatus, 
           if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko
        from
            widoc_config_group cfg_g
            join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
             join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
            join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
            join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
            join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
            join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
            left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
            left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
        where
             cfg_g.idclient = 3683
            #wc.idclientAssociated = 1865
            and cfg_g.identitytype=73003
            and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
            )x) d
            group by department,company,config,idWidocConfigGroup
        ;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd,             group by department,company,config,idWidocConfigGroup' at line 74

Separated queries:

```
select
    department as Delegación,
    company as Compañía,
    config as Configuración,
    docs as Documentos,
    count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
    sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos",
    round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% incumplimiento"
 from
    (
    select 
       cd.name as department,
       cfg_g.name as config, 
       c.businessname as company, 
       (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
       wd.idDriver, 
       cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup, 
       cfg.idwidocconfig, 
       cfg.iddocument, 
       a.idstatus, 
       if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko
    from
        widoc_config_group cfg_g
        join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
         join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
        join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
        join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
        join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
        join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
        left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
        left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
    where
         cfg_g.idclient = 3683
        #wc.idclientAssociated = 1865
        and cfg_g.identitytype=73003
        and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        ) t
 group by department,company,config,idwidocconfiggroup;
```

Second query:

```
select
    department as "Delegación",
     company as Compañía,
     config as Configuración,
     docs as Documentos,
     count(distinct idClientTruck) as vehículos,
     sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos",
     round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% incumplimiento"
  from
     (
     select
      cd.name as department,    
        cfg_g.name as config, 
        c.businessname as company, 
        (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
        wv.idClientTruck, 
        cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup, 
        cfg.idwidocconfig, 
        cfg.iddocument, 
        a.idstatus, 
        if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko     
     from
       widoc_config_group cfg_g
         join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
           join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
         join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
         join widoc_vehicle wv on wv.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wv.idstatus=71001
         join client_truck t on t.idclient_truck=wv.idclienttruck and t.idstatus_truckpart=33005
         join widoc_fulfill_vehicle fv on fv.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fv.idwidocvehicle=wv.idwidocvehicle
         left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wv.idClientTruck
         left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
     where
     cfg_g.idclient = 3683
         #wc.idclientAssociated = 3683
         and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
         and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
         ) t
     group by department,company,config,idwidocconfiggroup;
```

They both work fine.

Comment: change`)x) d.....` into `)x
            group by department,company,config,idWidocConfigGroup)`

Comment: Same error, even if i remove "d" after ")", then this error apears: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idClientTruck' in 'field list'

Comment: What do you want to aggregate? You have to add a group by in every statement where you do aggregation. Can you add a short example of the expected result?

Comment: Did you try to run each one of this two Select statements individually ? Are they ok ?

Comment: Try to split your query and check whether it is working then merge into a single query.

Comment: I don't know how to transform queries to code can someone do it please? Both separate queries are now in my question.

Comment: Ramon, you have written the same query two times. Also, do check the answer from @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, he made some good pointers.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Take a look at [mcve] before you start!

Comment: It is not the same query.

Comment: @Ramón do you have the original working query, since you don't have any clue. I think you just added some lines to make it work but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I found lots of problem in your query

1. for union and union all number of the column should have to be same in both query selection but you don't have that in both queries
   1st selection number of column is 7

   ```
        select
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        config as "Configuración Vehículos",
        docs as "Documentos Vehículos",
        count(distinct idClientTruck) as vehículos,
        sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos Vehículos",
        round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% Docs. Vehículos"
   ```

and

where 2nd selection number of column is 5

```
    select
    config as "Configuración Conductores",
    docs as "Documentos Conductores",
    count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
    sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos Conductores",
    round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% Docs. Conductores"
```

2. `group by department,company,config,idWidocConfigGroup` need to place in correct place  it should be after `alias x`
3. remove unnecessary alias name like d and t

Comment: If i remove "d" and "t" error: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias